# Why I recived user-set on my Nmap analyze?

Tags: nmap

I executed this command:

```
nmap -sn -n --scan-delay 1s --max-retries 0 -Pn --packet-trace --reason <IP>
```

And I received this response:

> Host is up, received user-set.

It seems that *Nmap* thinks that inserted IP address is my native PC's IP address. However, it is not.

I am using Nmap on my native *Windows 10*, *ZenMap*, against a *Windows 7* virtual machine.

How can I change this situation?

Comment: First of all why did you combine -sn and -Pn. The first flag tells nmap not to scan ports and -Pn tells nmap to skip pinging(host discovery)

Comment: I am probing the `nmap -sn -n --scan-delay 1s --max-retries 0` command on different situations. This command does  ARP Scan, if not achieve results Ping Scan and if not achieve results Port Scan to 80 and 443 ports. I wan to provoke the Port Scan for this case.

Comment: Try with basic command nmap <target> and see how that behaves

Comment: I can't do it, because the command that I have told you has a specific behavior, it is not a simple Port Scan.

Comment: Dude, this will never scan ports because you put -sn flag there. Get rid of it and try.

Comment: If you read my second comment, this command do a Port Scan to 80 and 443.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75766/discussion-between-iratzar-carrasson-bores-and-tryna-learn-somethin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user-set` reason is shown if the reason is set to `ER_USER`. (This is stored in an enum in portreasons.cc of the nmap github repository.

This mapping is set in `portreasons.cc`:

```
reason_map_type::reason_map_type(){
reason_map[ER_RESETPEER] = reason_string("reset","resets");
reason_map[ER_UNKNOWN] = reason_string("unknown-response","unknown-responses");
reason_map[ER_USER] = reason_string("user-set","user-sets");
```

There is only a single point in the NMAP project when the ER_USER reason is set, and that is in this piece of code:

```
...
        if (pingtype == PINGTYPE_NONE && !arpping_done)
          hs->hostbatch[i]->reason.reason_id = ER_USER;
        else
          hs->hostbatch[i]->reason.reason_id = ER_LOCALHOST;
...
```

Your `Pn` flag indicates that there should be no ping used, so the above `pingtype == PINGTYPE_NONE`, is set by this flag, which validates the first part of the conditional.

Now, there's only the `!arpping_done` left, which appears to be "`false`" in your result, as the reason ER_USER is printed in the end.

The flag is initialized as `false` 
And the only code that sets it to true is:

```
  /* First I'll do the ARP ping if all of the machines in the group are
     directly connected over ethernet.  I may need the MAC addresses
     later anyway. */
  if (hs->hostbatch[0]->ifType() == devt_ethernet &&
      hs->hostbatch[0]->af() == AF_INET &&
      hs->hostbatch[0]->directlyConnected() &&
      o.sendpref != PACKET_SEND_IP_STRONG &&
      (pingtype == PINGTYPE_ARP || o.implicitARPPing)) {
    arpping(hs->hostbatch, hs->current_batch_sz);
    arpping_done = true;
  }
```

/* No other interface types are supported by ND ping except devt_ethernet
     at the moment. */
  if (hs->hostbatch[0]->ifType() == devt_ethernet &&
      hs->hostbatch[0]->af() == AF_INET6 &&
      hs->hostbatch[0]->directlyConnected() &&
      o.sendpref != PACKET_SEND_IP_STRONG &&
      (pingtype == PINGTYPE_ARP || o.implicitARPPing)) {
    arpping(hs->hostbatch, hs->current_batch_sz);
    arpping_done = true;
}

Which might seem confusing, but is explained in the comment:

> I'll do the ARP ping if all of the machines in the group are
>        directly connected over ethernet.

[Source](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/ff623002492e50a7412c32c7a083bdec4f10b929/targets.cc)

So ARP Scanning will only be done if you're targeting a machine on the local network, which i assume isn't the case.

Also from the docs, to explain the code above a little better than i did:

> For machines on a local ethernet network, ARP scanning will still be performed (unless --disable-arp-ping or --send-ip is specified) because Nmap needs MAC addresses to further scan target hosts. In previous versions of Nmap, -Pn was -P0 and -PN.

As to why no further results are shown:

**-Sn (No port scan)**

> This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available hosts that responded to the host
>   discovery probes. This is often known as a “ping scan”, but you can
>   also request that traceroute and NSE host scripts be run. This is by
>   default one step more intrusive than the list scan, and can often be
>   used for the same purposes. It allows light reconnaissance of a target
>   network without attracting much attention. Knowing how many hosts are
>   up is more valuable to attackers than the list provided by list scan
>   of every single IP and host name.

**So, a short conclusion:**
`Pn` causes you to get a true `pingtype == PINGTYPE_NONE`, the reason that ARP Ping is interpreted as `false` is likely that the target device is not in yoru LAN, or isn't responding to ARP queries. `sn` tells nmap NOT to scan ports.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this means it could be lying when it says "Host is up"?